# Android layout weights broken down by ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-xml

I'm creating an activity. It has a main menu. Here is my xml;

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="84"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_background_shape"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And it's output like this;

[image]

I want to add images into the numbered areas. When I add them, Here is the xml.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="84"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_background_shape"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/main_menu_katilimcilar" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/main_menu_etkinlikler" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/main_menu_imza_gunleri" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/main_menu_fuar_haritasi" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/main_menu_fuar_hakkinda" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/main_menu_paylas" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output like this;

[image]

Layout weights lost because of the images. I want to scale images(with it's aspect ratio) and make layouts not to lost weights.

How can I do it?

**EDIT:**
After @pratik's answer here is the output;

[image]

Comment: what you have did this, 14 layouts to put just 6 images, create only one linear layout and give weight directly to ImageView not to LinearLayout. It will manage by itself.

Comment: <ImageView ... android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Comment: @pratik how can I do it? can give me an example?

Comment: @A.S. i tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: Why so many LinearLayouts ? There is just need of two `LinearLayout` only and 3 `ImageView` inside `LinearLayout's` and assign equal weights to all three images.

Comment: TRy t set the width of your ImageView to 0dp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Current Duration Label -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

              <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

              <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your answer and doesn't work. I want left and right spaces in my layout. I updated the question. Can you look at?

Comment: check updated answer. Use margin to leave some space.

Answer (score 0):

Sry but your Layout is very nested:

Try two LinearLayouts below each other: put in each Linearlayout(weightSum="3")
3 ImageViews with weight=1 and width="0dp"

Or use a GridView if you want more pictures (I would do that)

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum=".9" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum=".9" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```